# Forme interronégative pour une tournure négative (La Peste, Camus)

Tags: sens, négation

> « Il y a bien longtemps, les chrétiens d'Abyssinie voyaient dans la
> peste un moyen efficace, d'origine divine, de gagner l'éternité. Ceux
> qui n'étaient pas atteints s'enroulaient dans les draps des pestiférés
> afin de mourir certainement. Sans doute, cette fureur de salut n'est-elle pas recommandable.

La dernière phrase signifie « sans doute, cette fureur de salut n'est
pas recommandable ».

Il y a dans cette construction une répétition du sujet au moyen d'un pronom qui est placé de telle manière que la forme qui résulte est celle de l'interro négation.

Quel nom donne-t-on à cette construction et quel est son but ou l'effet recherché en l'utilisant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On pourrait l'appeler une inversion stylistique mais l'inversion après "sans doute" est si courante à l'écrit que certains la considèrent [obligatoire](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/doute-sans-doute). Son absence est en tout cas souvent ressentie comme "negligée" rapporte Grevisse.

> **§383 a) 2°** L'inversion est très fréquente, surtout dans la langue littéraire, après *et encore* (= *malgré cela*), *tout au plus*, *à peine*, *peut-être*, *sans doute*, *encore moins*.
> [...] sans inversion (ce que nos témoins ressentent souvent comme
> négligé) [...]
> *LBU* 14<sup>e</sup> édition.

L'effet recherché de la phrase complète de Camus est évidemment l'humour, noir ici.